# value wont pass to controller from provider angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller

So I have a controller and a provider which I am trying to pass a value from the provider to the controller, nothing too complex. I have been through several tuts and forum threads about this but non eof the e=suggestions are working. Worst off I am not getting any errors in my console either, just a blank page. I am sure that this is something stupid small Im missing but I am stumped.

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

   app.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope, Stocks) {
        $scope.stock = Stocks;
   });

app.provider('Stocks', function() {
    this.name = 'some name';
    this.$get = function() {
        this.name = 'Ford Motors'
        return this.name;
    };
});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/settings', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
  });
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-csp="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Presently</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

settings.html

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="stock_name">{{stock.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `app.controller('SettingsCtrl',['$scope','Stocks', function($scope, Stocks){}])`

Comment: @PatrickEvans this would only cause problems with minified code but even so it would throw an error (unknown provider).

Comment: @IlanFrumer _"Use the inline bracket notation which wraps the function to be injected into an array of strings (representing the dependency names) followed by the function to be injected:"_ [a note about minification](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#controller_a-note-on-minification) as for the unknown provider that maybe true, i thought they would be included just like directives and services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `Stocks` provider

```
app.provider('Stocks', function() {
    this.name = 'some name';
    this.$get = function() {
        this.name = 'Ford Motors'
        return this; //<-----instead of 'this.name'
    };
});
```

Because `this.name` always return `name` not `Stocks object`. Now your expression `{{stock.name}}` will evaluate.

Comment: Thats what it was! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

#### You should use `ngView` :

```
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
```

#### And put the content inside the template:

```
<!-- templates/settings.html' -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="stock_name">{{stock.name}}</div>
</div>
```

#### Also redirect to you route:

```
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/settings'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I left that part out of my example to simplify the problem at hand. I have included the code for settings.html and the ng-view to help avoid confusion

Comment: What about `otherwise`?